# Firefox makes two HTTP requests

Tags: firefox

Ok this is weird.

If I make a request to a page, where it's text/html, firefox makes one request.

If I make a request to a page, where it's application/xml, firefox makes two requests.

In IE, Google Chrome, it one makes one in both cases.

Any ideas why the two requests, and how I can force just the one?

Comment: example code plllllllzzzzzzzz

Comment: I had an issue once where the antivirus suite on the computer caused this. We spent a good while debugging this, trying to figure out why IE sent two requests every time, when other browsers didn't. I'm aware that in your case it's Firefox, but it may still be worth checking into.

Comment: @PiPeep, that queston is about an OGG video file, and the answer is specifically about seeking in a video file. This is an html file. Firefox has no need to "seek" in the html file, so that question cannot be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

I've had a similar issue if the encoding of the page didn't match the `<meta>` tag. If the page was encoded using default windows encoding, but the meta tag specified UTF-8, then firefox would stop downloading once it reached a non-ascii character (e.g. æ,ø or å) and it would redownload the page from the beginning. This would mess up view counts and lots of other logic since the server side script would run twice.

It might be that if you do not start your page with `<?xml ?>`, but claim that it is, then Firefox will redownload the page again as html (text/html) and process it as html.

Comment: I was just having this issue and after alot of messing with JS and apache...finally narrowed it down to the meta charset tag.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another possibility...

If the html code contains an empty img src attribute, then this causes a 2 http request in both Firefox and Chrome.  Currently, those are the ones that follow the standard to the letter, which states that an empty URI reference refers to the absolute base URI.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem with Firefox. Might help someone. 
FF was making two HTTP GET requests while Chrome didn't.

The problem was an empty `src=""` attribute.
Firefox considers such empty attribs for img/script... tags as the current url and GETs the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're making the request in a way that cause [HTTP Access Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) features to fire?

It is a fairly new standard, and new in [FF3.5][2] that can cause double GET requests.

In case you can sniff the requests server side: see if they contain the `Origin:` header.

[2]: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Server-Side_Access_Control Server-Side Access Control

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a wrong content-type header "image/jpg" sent with PHP-generated image. Double requests gone after I changed the type to "image/jpeg"

More info about this bug...
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=236858

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problem too and I've figured it out.THIS may be related to **Non-existent favicon.ico**. details [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403408),you can check it using following code(node.js),:

```
var http = require('http');
server = http.createServer(function (req,res){

    console.log(req.url);
    res.writeHeader(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    res.end("Hello World");
})
server.listen(8000);
console.log("httpd start @8000");
```

the result is expected to be:

```
httpd start @8000 
/ 
/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

The XML packet I was returning had a root node of `<feed>`

Firefox passes this twice for some reason, maybe as it's trying to identify if this is a valid ATOM/RSS feed. If not, just displays instead?

Changing root node to something else fixed the problem.

Thanks Marcus for starting me in the right direction.